# wake_up() with WK_MS won't work

Tags: event-handling, g-wan

I have changed the ms delay to 3000 in example stream2.c, on line 47, as seen below:

> ```
>   // ------------------------------------------------------------
>   // tell G-WAN when to run this script again (for the same request)
>   // ------------------------------------------------------------
>   wake_up(argv, 3000, WK_MS); // WK_MS:milliseconds, WK_FD:file_descriptor
> ```

It is expected to sleep 3 sec of each round, but it responds immediately. It seems that wake_up() with WK_MS won't work.
Are there any work-around?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version you are using but you should use `v4.12` or more recent: v4.12 is available to long-term G-WAN fans and registered users. The stream1/2/3.c examples have been tested and enhanced. Send an email to the G-WAN Team to get the latest archive.

Some G-WAN users have used these examples to query `remote database servers` or `remote back-end servers`, and this mechanism works very well.